# Extract VB.NET code from exe file

Tags: vb.net, decompiling

I made a program using VB and I lost the source code but I have the exe file. How  can I extract the code from the exe file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your exe is a .NET assembly (you tagged the question as VB.NET), you can reverse engineer your exe using tools such as [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: <-- this. It absolutely is possible - I've had to do it - and once again red gate are awesome. You can even convert it into C#...

Comment: Good to know in the future :-)

Comment: @annakata - Lutz Roeder (reflector author) is awesome, Red Gate are generous to keep a free version. Credit where credit is due!

Comment: Yeah- you might want to look at using FileGenerator for this approach: http://www.codeplex.com/FileGenReflector

Comment: Redgate took over Reflector from Lutz Roeder. So he is the actual hero :-)

Comment: You know I did wonder about that (since my app says Lutz Roeder all over it) - I just assumed he worked at red gate or something. Ah well, they're both awesome.

Answer (score 4):

If it's VB.NET you can use the [RedGate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) tool and the [FileDisassemler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) plugin to generate the source code. That is if the exe was not obfuscated

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged your question vb.net you might be able to retrieve quite some portions of your code using a .NET disassembler. For example try [Lutz Roeder's .Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or MS ildasm which comes with the .NET compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) (assuming .NET) to dissassemble the exe back into code. You will need to create your own class structure, but you can recover the code as any of the supported CLR languages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Salamander](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/), or one of the many other .net decompilers?

Answer (score 0):

Trey [VB Decompiler](http://www.vb-decompiler.org) and see if that works.